# ¿How to get some elements of a sublist into another sublist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I declare `letters` which one has many sublists, and I declare `max`.

What I am trying is to fill a new list `stringWithMax` with sublist of `letters`, but in a way that sublists just take the value from `1` to de index that `max` has in position `i`. For example, I want to fill `stringWithMax[0]` with `letters[0]` but I want to take the range from 1 to max[0], so that when I print `stringWithMax` it displays in console `[['a', 'c', 'b']]`, then fill `stringWithMax[1]` with values of `letters[1]` but just to take values from 1 to max[1], so that when I print again `stringWithMax` it displays in console `[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W']]` and consecutively get the same with the last line. So in a final way when I print `stringWithMax` the result in console shows `[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W'], ['R', 'X', 'N']]` and that is exactly as I want.

I have programmed this

```
letters = [['letters1', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'BUILD'], ['letter2','F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'SHOW', 'BUILD'], ['leters3','R', 'X', 'N', 'BUILD', 'SHOW']]
max = [4, 5, 4]

stringWithMax = []
def  reGet():
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        for x in range(1, max[i]): 
            stringWithMax.append(letters[i][x])
    print(stringWithMax)

reGet()
```

With this code I just get in console `['a', 'c', 'b', 'F', 'P', 'Z', 'W', 'R', 'X', 'N']` which is almost similar for what I want, but it is not a list with sublist as I want.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Your desired output is [['a', 'c', 'b'], ['F', 'P', 'Z', 'W'], ['R', 'X', 'N']]? Also, naming a list "max" isn't really recommended as it's also a builtin function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best for your code is to make use of [list comprehension](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5iLHR0P7xAhVdQjABHTLIAdkQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fpython%2Fpython_lists_comprehension.asp&usg=AOvVaw1IOzWD_PKyhr8BzEZglcf8)

So your code would be:

```
letters2 = [[subitem for subitem in item if len(subitem) == 1] for item in letters]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slice:

```
def reGet():
    for letter, upper in zip(letters, max):
        stringWithMax.append(letter[1:upper])
```

As you can see, I've also improved your code by using `zip` instead of indices. You can improve it further with a list comprehension:

```
stringWithMax = [letter[1:upper] for letter, upper in zip(letters, max)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, another case of list comprehensions.
Item is a nested list in list of letters, subitem is each word/letter inside the item. It checks if the length == 1 so you know it's just a letter.

```
letters2 = [[subitem for subitem in item if len(subitem) == 1] for item in letters]
```